# Python requests library corrupt image download

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-headers

I'm preparing a script for a project where I will be using Instagram API to cache images and display them. While testing the image download with some links off Wikipedia I ran into an issue.

Two of the images are not downloading correctly and I cant figure out why (**bold** links at the bottom)

both images are 1.86 KB when downloaded via the script. However, when I download them through Chrome they are sizably larger.

Note that the Anna's hummingbird link originally had the html encoding %27 just changed it while testing possible issues

```
class DL_IMGS:
    
    def __init__(self, data_pass):
        self.data = data_pass
    def img_downloader(self):
        dir_loc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
        }
        for url in self.data:
            print(url)
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream = True)
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            status = r.status_code
            if status == 200:
                response = requests.get(url)
                img_name = str(url).split('/')

                with open(dir_loc+"/image_cache/"+ img_name[-1] , "wb") as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
                    print ('Success : ' +str(status)+' : '+ url+'\n')
            else:
                print('Error : ' +str(status)+' : '+ url+'\n')

tester_image_links = ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Boats_at_Bhimili_beach_in_Visakhapatnam.jpg/1280px-Boats_at_Bhimili_beach_in_Visakhapatnam.jpg','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/RedcrestedTuraco.jpg/750px-RedcrestedTuraco.jpg','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Balaeniceps_rex.jpg/220px-Balaeniceps_rex.jpg','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Grey_crowned_crane_at_Martin_Mere.JPG',"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Anna's_hummingbird.jpg",'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Female_annas_hummingbird_hovering.jpg']

download = DL_IMGS(tester_image_links)

download.img_downloader()
```

Used wiki image links
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Boats_at_Bhimili_beach_in_Visakhapatnam.jpg/1280px-Boats_at_Bhimili_beach_in_Visakhapatnam.jpg

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/RedcrestedTuraco.jpg/750px-RedcrestedTuraco.jpg

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Balaeniceps_rex.jpg/220px-Balaeniceps_rex.jpg

**https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Grey_crowned_crane_at_Martin_Mere.JPG**

**[https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Anna's_hummingbird.jpg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Anna%27s_hummingbird.jpg)**

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Female_annas_hummingbird_hovering.jpg

Comment: I did not try that and see what you are talking about. I just ran the script again and one of the two problematic images are working. Seems like it could be a headers issue? I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh, awesome. I'm willing to bet that's the issue. seems to suggest a 100ms delay between requests. "Most users should limit themselves to a single connection, with a small delay (100ms or so) between requests to avoid a tight loop when there is an error condition." -- I'll add that in and see what happens.